# Spring Boot auto login Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, spring-security

Ive been at this for hours and still cant figure out why im getting `org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException`

Im working on a registration and login system.  I can create a User through a registration page and I can see it inputted into the database.  In the registration post method I then try to automatically login the user with an authentication manager but each time I get the same BadCredentialsException.  I check in my database and everything looks fine yet I still get the same error.  Im new to the authentication stuff so my mistake may be in plain site to others but not myself.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
        request.getSession();

        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));

        try{
            Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(token);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That is where I try to log in the User, with that code in which should Auto login the User I get the bad credentials exception.  I do save the User correctly before that.  I tried many different ways to auto login the user but none of them have worked.  Any ideas?

Edit:
Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/edit").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers(
    (A bunch of allowances to pages), "/").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .rememberMe()
    .key("myUniqueKey") 
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    .rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")
    .tokenValiditySeconds(100000000)
    .and()
    .logout()
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .clearAuthentication(true)
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .permitAll();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return auth;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throw Exception {
    return authenticationManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

Comment: Show us how did you implement the secruity ( Configurations  ) ?

Comment: I have a feeling that it has something to do with my Authentication Provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it to work, to be honest I dont know why I had this problem, I thought I tried all the ways to authenticate the users(Using plain text password/hashed and different ways of getting UserDetails).  I should really look more into authentication and stuff like that but for now, I found the fix through this post:
[hellokoding post](https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot/security-login-mysql-jsp/)